# When will session_id() return '' despite a successful session_start() in PHP?

Tags: php, session

The webserver is running PHP 5.3.10 and the code looks like this:

```
if (session_id() == '') {
    if (session_start()) {
       if (session_id() == '') {
          Log::warn("Session id was empty?!");
       }
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, this will every once in a while (much less than once every 1000 page renderings) log the warning text "Session id was empty?!".

Doing a second session_start() will result in a PHP notice about the session being started twice.

What could be causing this and are there any workarounds?

Comment: It might be a visitor with an empty PHP session ID cookie (possibly a spider or an attacker). Also look at `session_regenerate_id`.

Comment: You should be using `===`

Comment: Is there any output before session_start() is called?

Comment: @Dai is there a way to determine if that has happened?

Comment: @JimmyT. no output (if output had happened, it would have thrown errors due to headers already being sent)

Comment: It would only be a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Dai I think you're on the right track. At least I was able to simulate the exact same behaviour with the right cookie.